# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') with thunderclient

Tags: node.js, express, mern, thunderclient

I am using thunder client extension on vs code and I am requesting data from it. I tried changing names and my code a lot of times but it isnt working. Also i tried making name const but it is saying that name is undefined (void) so I think the problem is the req command is not getting my data from thunderclient.
here's my index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 4000;
const mongoDB = require("./db");
mongoDB();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
});
app.use('/api', require("./routes/CreateUser"));
app.use(express.json());
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

Createuser.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const User = require('../models/User')

router.post("/createuser", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await User.create({
            name: req.body.name,
            password: req.body.password,
            email: req.body.email,
            location: req.body.location,
        })
        res.json({ success: true })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.json({ success: false })
    }
})

module.exports = router
```

Thunderclient
[Thunderclient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7joJ.png)

So I guess I have some problems in my thunderclient as it is not sending the json data because name is returning void.

Answer (score 0):

The order of express middleware matters. You need to put the `app.use(express.json())` statement before using your API router.

```js
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api', require("./routes/CreateUser"));
```